# Independent probability example

Tags: probability

I'd like some input for this question.

The question says you have a fair die and do the following experiment:

- Roll the die once; let x be the outcome.
- Roll the die x times (independently); let y be the smallest outcome of these x rolls
- Roll the die y times (independently); let z be the largest outcome of these y rolls

Determine Pr(x = 1 and y = 2 and z = 3).

Here's how I tackled the question:

Let x be a random number between 1 and 6. The sample space for y would be such that there are X elements and each element can be the numbers 1 through 6. Since each event in sample space has a (1/6) chance of being 2, the Pr(y = 2) would be $$(1/6)^x$$

Likewise for z, the Pr(z = 3) is $$(1/6)^y$$

So the Pr(x = 1 and y = 2 and z = 3) is $$(1/6)*(1/6)^x*(1/6)^y$$

Comment: The second event does not have a uniform distribution. $P\{y = 6\} = (1/6)^x$, while $P\{y = 1\} = 1 - (5/6)^x$.

Comment: (Can't edit my above comment, sorry). Despite finding a general formula for all possible $x$, $y$ and $z$ is a bit difficult, answering the asked question is much more simpler. As these events are independent, we can obviously say that $P = P\{x=1\} * P\{y = 2 | x = 1\} * P \{z = 3 | y = 2 | x = 1\} = 1/6 * 1/6 * 5/36 = 5/1296.$

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski I'm having a hard time understanding why P(y=2|x=1) = 1/6 and P(z=3|y=2|x=1) = 5/36?

Comment: The first means "the lowest outcome of $x = 1$ roll equals $2$" - it's obviously just probability of rolling $2$. The second similarly means "the highest outcome of $y = 2$ rolls equals $3$". You may draw a table and will see that only outcomes $(1,3); (3,1); (2,3); (3,2); (3,3)$ give the highest equals $3$. Hence we have $5$ outcomes out of total $36$ possible outcomes for $2$ rolls.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski Oh I see! So we should consider the fact that x = 1 and y = 2. I was thrown off since the question mentioned they were independent and I assumed that each event was to be considered regardless of the previous roll's outcome. Thanks!

Comment: @Waves The individual die results are independent, but the random variables $X,Y,Z$ are clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

The individual die results are independent, but the random variables are clearly not.

To roll a value of $x$ on $1$ toss can be done in $1$ way of the $6$ possible rolls of the die.

To roll a minumum value of $y$ on $x$ tosses, count the ways to roll $x$ results of no less than $y$ minus the ways to roll $x$ results of no less than $y+1$, out of $6^x$ possible outcomes.

Similarly to roll a maximum value of $z$ on $y$ tosses, count the ways to roll $y$ results of no more than $z$ minus the ways to roll $y$ results of no more than $z-1$, out of $6^y$ possible outcomes.

$$\begin{align}
 \mathsf P(X=x) & = \frac 1 6
\\[2ex]
 \mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x) & = \frac{(7-y)^x - (6-y)^x}{6^x}
\\[1ex]
 \mathsf P(Y=2\mid X=1) & = \frac{1}{6}
\\[3ex]
 \mathsf P(Z=z\mid Y=y) & = \frac{z^y-(z-1)^y}{6^y}
 \\[2ex]
\mathsf P(Z=3\mid Y=2) & = \frac{3^2-2^2}{6^2} 
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{5}{6^2}
\\[3ex]
 \mathsf P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z)
 & = \mathsf P(X=1)\;\mathsf P(Y=2\mid X=1)\;\mathsf P(Z=3\mid Y=2)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{5}{1296}
\end{align}$$